# How to get answers for sure

Tags: support, questions, answers

I just want to know how I can make sure that my question will get answered. Sometimes, my questions remain unanswered. Is this because noone knows the answer, or — more likely — because noone knows that my question has been asked?

When I ask a new question, how are other users notified about it? Do they simply happen to see the question while browsing?

In short: how can I get someone to answer my query for sure?

Sorry if I sound desperate for answers, I'm simply new to android and forums.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, kiki! Just so you know, the rules here are [a little different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) than you might expect.

Comment: I'll bet that these questions would fare better on the proposed Android Developers site, if it ever made it as far as beta.  Too bad it'll probably get canned/merged first.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question-on-so - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/how-to-ask-great-questions

Comment: @Ladybug: He's not asking how to improve his questions.  His questions are fine.  Did you look at them?

Comment: @Aarobot: If you want answers, you need a good question (and bumping). There is no other way. See also Jeff's answer. It's all covered in the dupe links. I do not have to look at his questions for that.

Comment: @Ladybug: Yes, agreed, good questions are a requirement for good answers.  They are not, however, a guarantee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some helpful advice for you at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Also, the [core faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) itself has some advice:

> In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Comment: so its basically besed on ur luck, besides the question quality? Well, I wanted to know how users get to answering questions. They simply browse the unanswered questions and try to answer them? Will flagging a post for the attention of the moderator be of any use?

Comment: @kiki - NO! Flagging is used to report abuse or some other problem, NOT for getting answers.

Comment: ... Although that doesn't stop people from trying it anyway. We usually get three or four of those a week.

Answer (score 6):

When you ask a new question it is put on top at the top of the list of questions (at least when you view the main page or the [active questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) subpage). Also, until at least one answer is there and upvoted, your question will show up in the list of [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered). However, there is no guaranteed way to get an answer. That may have various reasons, for example:

- there is no answer (e.g. "What's the meaning of live?")
- the answer is difficult and will take some time to implement
- your question is not well-posed (read Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for hints how to avoid that)

Comment: Beat me to the "Writing the Perfect Question" answer... +1 to you!

Comment: This is all well and good, but if you look at his questions, you'll see that they are actually generally good questions, clearly-written and on-topic.  I don't think that a generic list of reasons and advice is all that helpful here.

Comment: @Aarobot: that's the best answer I can come up with. There simply *is* no guarantee