# Unanswered questions in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Most of the times Stackoverflow users reply to my support requests.
But sometimes i have questions that didn't answered.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) there is 623k for whole community.

I try to solve that problems by myself for days.
My question is what should I do when my question wasn't answered even after a week?
In other forums, I post a message in same topic to tell that I still have that problem.
But I don't know the best practice to do in stackoverflow in that situation.
Thank you

Comment: Edit and **improve** your question or/and post a bounty on it.

Comment: Also take a look at this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122809/why-are-my-questions-remaining-unanswered-for-a-long-time/122815#122815