# What does a Real Question look like ?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I am new in here so if my question violated the rules, I will delete it.

Yesterday I asked a question [Need help for php web based game](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11527409/996493). Before I post a question I already read `How to Ask` then i post my problem.

but in a few minute /hours I just got downvote and someone ask to add a homework tag then now it's

```
closed as not a real question by ..
```

Actually I don't understand why. In `How to ask` the first one `Do your homework` in there I already post that I already try but got nothing , the second `Be specific` I already provide the last code of my problem that I already fix some error and the third `Make it relevant to others` as I already mention in the comment that my project is find source in internet then fix it, in the internet the code itself is have many error and I already fix it and hope to get some answer from here to expand the game, in google itself I see there is someone who also find that game so it's relevant to others I think.

But I didn't get any answer and my question is closed.

So I just want to ask how the real question is look like? Did I made any mistake when posting a question?

Comment: +1 for coming here to ask instead of rage-quitting.

Comment: You can view other question for example.

Comment: @Lucifer I already see other question and i think its same, give some information,  give the code and say the problem. It's same with what i post but why my question closed

Comment: Can you paste a link to the question you are referring to in this question. If its possible to get a link to a closed question.

Comment: @OzairKafray this is the link of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527409/need-help-for-php-web-based-game

Comment: Well, you could start with a rewrite of your SO question...because I have no idea what it says and what the question is.

Comment: @UristMcBobby no idea what the question is ? so i have to post a new question in SO ? can i got ban for asked question if i do this ? if no i will make a new one with more details and try to make my question clear

Comment: read this answer, I think it may help a bit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122809/why-are-my-questions-remaining-unanswered-for-a-long-time/122815#122815

Comment: Just a comment on your grammar: it lacks punctuation. Even in your question here, there are 4-5 lines of text without a full-stop.

Comment: @devzlyx - I wouldn't re-ask the same question. Instead, follow the advice of the various people here and try to edit the existing one into a much clearer question. We can edit the grammar and punctuation into shape, but as it stands I don't even really know what you're asking. Once this has been edited into a clear question, flag it for a moderator to take a look at it and we might be able to get it reopened.

Answer (score 16):

IMO the main problem with the question is that you did not put enough effort in it. You don't even clearly state what you are trying to achieve. You don't explain what you have tried, what didn't work etc.. As it is now, it sounds like you have a homework and you just want it get done. There are lots of people on SO who would love to help you, but no one would want to do your homework.

Here are a list of problems with your question, I think you should address:

- you have lot's of grammar errors and it's hard to understand what you want to do(for example the question you ask here is written in much higher standard)
- you are missing punctuation
- you did not **clearly** explain what you are trying to do
- you did not explain what doesn't work, what have you tried
- you posted your whole source code, instead you should post only relevant part of it. People don't have time to go through such a long code

Comment: lol @ "lot's of grammar errors" - deliberate, I'm sure!

Answer (score 5):

> So I just want to ask how the real question is look like? Did I made any mistake when posting a question?

Well for one, there is a basic lack of grammar in your question. And I'm not talking about just your unwillness to properly capitalize the word `I`. You have 5 paragraphs and exactly *one* sentence-ending punctuation. That makes it rather difficult to read and understand what the problem is.

What's strange is that your question here is much clearer than the question you asked on SO.

Second, you didn't really explain what you're trying to do very well. You said, "i found a keno games". OK. Does that mean that you're trying to *implement* a [Keno game?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keno) If that's the idea, it's a good idea to inform us of what a Keno game is.

Comment: well I'm not so good in english, In my hometown, english is not the first language, but in my college english is the priority so I'm still learning it. Oc I understand about it, but how to edit the closed question ? have i make a new one ? I really need the answer because I already try for almost 24 hours everyday without getting any result. This head is almost stuck

Comment: @devzlyx: There is an edit link near the bottom of your question, on the left.

Comment: Lack of punctuation and capitalization isn't exactly something that can be explained by not being a native English speaker.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, your phrasing and grammar are really problematic - it's very very difficult to understand you.

Beyond that, though, your major problem is that **you haven't narrowed your question down to a single problem.** You write :

> so i want to ask how to make beside it give a point it also give which number is win so if 5 point it will show 5 numbers and how to count how many numbers that we choose ?

But "how do I write code that does (X)?" isn't a problem; it's programming work that needs to be done. Think of somebody asking "how do I write code for a complete operating system?": somebody could provide all the code, but it's fundamentally not a question - it's asking somebody else to deal with the code-writing part.

In your case, you might write something like: "I've gotten to the point where the program recognizes how many numbers have won, but I'm not managing to figure out which numbers are the winning ones. Which variables have this information?". Or maybe your problem is one of display: "I'm having trouble displaying the numbers that the program's chosen as winning." Or something else (I'm not really delving into the question here...). The point is *be specific*; narrow it down to some particular difficulty. And once you've done that, you can explain what you've already tried in a way that will be helpful for people answering (for example, "I though variable X has the information, but when I try to get it I get something wrong, maybe I'm using the wrong access methods?").

Answer (score 2):

The word "real" is not what characterizes your question. For sure is a real question but the problem here is that’s looks like a small project.

A Good question is the one **that all ready focus on the problem** and ask for help about the problem it self and not for how to make a full program or library to work. When some one did not shows that all ready know what the code do but in one line is lost, then that’s why is starts get -1

Here in SO people are for help, and **help is not make the work for you**. Help is to give you a hand when you are down and make you standup and continue, is not to carry you on the shoulders. Is not that you do not have legs to steps by your self, is just you are lazy to use it, and the rest refuse to gets you on their shoulders.

One more minus is that you do not have reputation, and you are a two day user. A user with high reputation and months of  helping on SO gets "a little more respect" when ask a question and maybe (at least me) even if he ask for difficult thinks other try to help him back because he is prove that is help back.

I have write some more about answering on SO in this answer: [Why are my questions remaining unanswered for a long time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122809/why-are-my-questions-remaining-unanswered-for-a-long-time/122815#122815)

Comment: I'm still confuse like what a small project or big project, if my question is small project so if someone ask about their web problem, is it small project ? **that all ready focus on the problem** ? I already provide the last source that I already edit and I ask a problem that already make me stuck so I think its already just focus on problem ( maybe I will make more detail ). I don't have a reputation because I'm new in here and I really need answer for my question. so if there any wrong again beside this ?

Comment: @devzlyx a small project is the one that I need more than 30minutes to find a solution. I have done that some times but look for example one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981084/virtual-listview-for-asp-net/10981815#10981815  The user have 25k and I write from nothing all the code and give to him.

Comment: @devzlyx When the question is focus on the real problem, then its easy to give an answer right away, if you see the answers are withing minutes.

Comment: When I post my question I don't know is it small project or not, for myself I already try for almost 24 hours and for around 2 days but I can't find my solution and always stuck that's why I post in here try to see the answer and learn from it. Well in my question I give a detail and my problem is when I try to expand the game and its error, is the real problem like a error in the code ?