# I want to know how to fix my questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have several downvoted questions and some of them were closed by others. So I want to fix my questions but I don't know what is wrong with them. How do I fix my questions so that I can write a new question?

Here are a few of my questions:

- [Is this the best way to communicate between processes by using shared memory in local system or between different machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083107/is-this-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-processes-by-using-shared-memory-in)
- [How can I make this MATLAB code fast (m-file script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823157/how-can-i-make-this-code-fastm-file-script)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847302/can-c-python-fortran-java-languages-be-highlighted-in-one-document-of-eclipse

Comment: I don't think any of them are salvageable.  Unfortunately, deleting them will most likely [question-ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997) you.

Comment: The best thing to do at this point is write some stellar answers to other questions where you can. You need some votes under your belt if you want to ultimately get rid of those questions. Take a few minutes and browse for highly up voted questions and answers in your favorite tags, look at what makes them stand out. That's the kind of stuff you should try to produce in the very near future.

Comment: you mean that I need to response a good answer to other questions which I am interested in? and check the best voted questions and answers to check how to answer the question? if this is the only way and if I understand right, I will do like that.

Comment: Robert Harvey: what is wrong with them do you think, I am asking you for near future

Comment: Any question that asks for a "Yes/No" answer does not fit Stack Overflow. So judging purely from the title, "Is this the best way to ..." means the answer will be either "Yes, it is" or "No, it isn't" and it does not fit Stack Overflow. You will have to focus the question on the actual problem and maybe ask for ways to improve.

Answer (score 2):

I will start and focus on one question of you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847302/can-c-python-fortran-java-languages-be-highlighted-in-one-document-of-eclipse

This question show that you either never read some programming books about how C for example works, either never take some lessons about the basic of programming. So is logical to get so many down voters because all the rest understand that you maybe love programming, but you did not spend some time to learn programming and you may believe that with questions you can learn.

The truth is that you can not fully learn programming by questions – you can do many thinks, help on issues, find solutions on problems, the questions and answers is also a very good library because we can not remember anything, anyway, the questions and answers are a lot of things, but they can not teach you and make you a programmer.

So from my point of view, I suggest to start from the basics, find a teacher or a school or find some books that you can learn from, be a better programmer, and your questions will be better one. Ops this is too general answer, is logical that if you be better programmer then maybe do not even need to make questions.

Ok, the point here is that the rest understand that you have a lot to learn first – and if you know them, then you never ask those questions – and again the issue here "if not make question, how do you learn ?" I say that before, you can not learn from questions to be programmer (in my opinion)

Also you can read that answer that can help you with the rest two questions of you: [Why are my questions remaining unanswered for a long time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122809/why-are-my-questions-remaining-unanswered-for-a-long-time/122815#122815)

Comment: of the -1 I know, something is not working for me on meta :) I am working on it.... :)

Comment: Ha, that downvote was somehow mine, though I have no clue why. Huge thumbs, small mobile most likely. Undid it. :)

Comment: @Bart Huge thumbs, give huge hugs :)