# Post-ban not removed after editing my questions

Tags: support, post-ban

I was recently banned from posting questions. I edited my earlier questions to remove the ban, but it is still in place. What can I still do?

Comment: Can you link to the questions that you have edited please?

Comment: @jonsca Sum total of two revisions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759028/murali?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Though the exact details are unknown to anyone but the developers, I would assume that just editing them is not sufficient. A significant increase in reputation might be necessary as well. Have you been receiving upvotes on your posts as a result of editing them? The best advice probably is to keep at it and gain reputation in other ways still possible to you.

Comment: The first question still has a wall of poorly formatted code, but it's improved a teeny-tiny bit.  Format the code as you would have it in your editor, with the proper spacing.  For the second one, you just slapped a link on that had helped you.  If you're going to ask and answer your own question, it should still be of good quality so that someone can find it later and use the information, and the answer should be an answer (with more than just a link).  All in all, not much improvement, I'm afraid.

Comment: And don't merely improve the downvoted questions. Improve all your content. Anything that can balance out your negatively scored contributions might help and can certainly never harm. Something like [your first question for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972545/how-to-extract-html-contenti-have-a-html-page-how-to-extract-the-data-inside-a) can do with some serious formatting improvement. This can't be what you want it to look like.

Comment: Editing is not directly relevant. To have the ban lifted your posts must get **upvotes**. If you edit properly and make the questions good enough, upvotes will come and the ban will be lifted, but you can't expect this to be instant or trivial process.

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions?  Your total score, while overall negative, isn't as bad as some I've seen.  Leads me to think that maybe you have a couple of highly downvoted questions that you deleted yourself (or were deleted for you)

Comment: Did you bother to read the page pointed to by the link within the message that you get when trying to post a question?

Comment: The poor guy is asking how to be unbanned and is getting downvotes for that ? I hope those down-voters get banned some day to see what it's like.

Comment: @Fred Don't know sir why they are like this. ?????

Comment: I too am trying to re-instate my asking privileges due to downvotes, and even good answers have been downvoted because some people are so picky. People are way too harsh on new members here..

Answer (score 7):

Just editing isn't enough for an auto-ban to be lifted.

The point is to *improve* your posts. The measurement for improvement is the rate of deleted/closed questions, as well as the score of your posts.

The correct course of action would be to post a question here on meta, something along the lines of:

> I was auto-banned from Stack Overflow, and I have improved my questions. Please review them once more! Here are the questions I've
>   improved:
>
> - Question 1
> - Question 2
> - Question 3

Let the community review your questions again, and see if they have been improved enough for positive voting/reopening. If your improvements are visible, your ban would be lifted in no-time.

Answer (score 7):

> What can I still do?

I was also auto-banned from making questions - to say the truth if I know that they will ban me I will act differently when I delete one of my question, anyhow, what I did is that: **I start answering questions the best way I can**, and [boom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122809/why-are-my-questions-remaining-unanswered-for-a-long-time/122815#122815), the limitation removed.

Comment: Sure, the OP can try that, but it doesn't work for everyone. I tried that for months on end, but it never resolved my ban.

Comment: @MrLister Its also take to me months. I really do not know how its works, I just share my experience. In my case also the questions have been deleted, so I do not have anything to improve.

Comment: I too answered few questions but that is vain attempt

Comment: @Murali No is not - but what you expect to return in the previous status in a day ?. Also I have see your questions and did not see any change or try to make them better, you need a lot of work - I did a lot of work to remove it, and now I respect a lot more the site.

Comment: @Aristos  Ok. I try hard