# How can I gain rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I always get down-votes for my questions (also one of question is closed too) because people don't realize that my knowledge of programming is not very strong. I am a coding enthusiast and I would like some tips to reputations.

What can I do?

Comment: Should I say "Please, no downvotes," or not?

Comment: No. If you do that, you can be certain you will be put in the Very Low Quality queue.

Comment: Before asking question, go through this [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: You can also check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

Comment: @bjb568 Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ToonKrijthe This link has no info that works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read these two links to learn what should be in your question so you cann't get downvote:

1. [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)
2. [How to ask great questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/how-to-ask-great-questions)

And you need to do some work before ask any question:

1. Try to find an answer by searching the archives of the forum you plan to post to.
2. Try to find an answer by searching the Web.
3. Try to find an answer by reading the manual.
4. Try to find an answer by reading a FAQ.
5. Try to find an answer by inspection or experimentation.
6. Try to find an answer by asking a skilled friend.
7. If you're a programmer, try to find an answer by reading the source code.

And also here is a page where you can find that how to ask a question.
Here is the link of that: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask**

Comment: This is a great tip! Thank you so much for telling me about these links. It helps a lot!

Comment: @Joseph My pleasure in helping you :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you post your question, do some research (and describe your research in the question). Search to make sure your question isn't a duplicate. Use proper and formal English. Then you should be able to get answers and upvotes from others users.