# How do I avoid asking opinion-based questions?

Tags: support, questions

I [often](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/113623/) ask opinion-based questions on Stack Exchange only to have them downvoted and closed, as I often do not know if a question (and its answers) are opinion-based until they are answered. To prevent this, how can I determine if a question is opinion-based before posting it?

Comment: Try to avoid asking why people do things. Concentrate on how to do whatever it is you want to do instead.

Comment: [How to ask great questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/how-to-ask-great-questions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This list is far from exhaustive but I try to avoid asking:

- why people do things;
- whether people (including you) should do things;
- for best practices; and
- generally for the best anything.

What someone answers in each case is likely to be their opinion.

Asking whether/how something can be done, after showing what I've tried to do to answer my own question, is unlikely to be closed as seeking opinions.

Comment: and questions asking abt _Best Practices_