# Where can I ask about learning material? (And how can I find the appropriate place for my questions in the future?)

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I wanted to ask for some recommendations for JavaScript tutorials on Stack Exchange, when I noticed, that this kind of question is against the rules.

Then I found *[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and I thought that was sort of a place where my question might fit - recommendations are okay there - but then I noticed that such question would be against the rules there too:

The [Software Recommendations guide](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> While this includes software libraries for development use, note that **recommendations of tutorials**, data sources, media libraries (e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic

I'm an autodidact learner (as most of the people here, I've heard), and I got really pleased when I found this page. I'd be pretty disappointed if I had to realize that there are some topics I have to find getting answers somewhere else. :( (as you can see in the question I wanted to post, I have problems with googling also. Ohh, damned I be!)

**So is there a place for such questions? What's the best way to find out which site fits any tech related question I might want to ask? I seem to realize that I had misunderstood the aims of this website, but can you tell me why the rules are this strict? What should I do, when I don't even know the question?**

---

Here's question I was about to ask:

> I have some knowledge of [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) and [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29). I've learned about [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) and I'd like to play around with it. My problem is that before I got into it, I should have some understanding of [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), I'm looking for a guide for this case.
>
> I'm new to web development and I'm not particularly interested in JavaScript. If I could google better, probably I would already have the answer, but all I found when I was looking around  was:
>
> - either JavaScript tutorials which takes too much time to explain basic programming ideas
> - Too advanced tutorials which goes way deeper into the topic then I was intended to.
>
> Do you have some good material for this?

Comment: There is no such place for a question like this on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Tapping on the "asking-questions" tag included in your question (and looking at some of the first uses) turns up this Q&A: "[How to ask great questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8072/282094)", along with other similar questions. Similarly the "questions" tag has a ["Learn more"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/questions/info) link which offers some additional information. Searching this site leads to the FAQ Q&A: "[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/282094)" - all of which should be helpful.

Comment: Some tag wikis are extremely well documented and often contain links to off-site resources so you don't have to ask about them: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 4):

Software recommendations and hardware recommendations are *unusual* sites.

Stack Exchange (SE) has experimented with more general sites for things like this in the past, and well they don't work. External resources are also out of our control, so an answer is possibly going to go obsolete.

Stack Exchange isn't a *recommendations* engine. It’s a Q&A engine.

Some things, like specific recommendations of learning material just don't work here.

Also

> either JS tutorials which takes too much time to explain basic programming ideas

Just skip the stuff you know :D

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to ask for some recommendations for JS tutorial on stack exchange

This was on-topic on Stack Overflow in the past, e.g [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508149). Some of those threads are now locked but kept for historical reasons and because of the value they contain.

> Where to ask about learning material?

It depends on the [site in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). A given resource request being on-topic is a per-site policy. You can check what is on-topic in the help center of each site ["What topics can I ask about here? "](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Some of the language sites allow requests for learning/reading material, e.g. ["Are questions asking for resources on-topic?"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16), with the debate being if such requests should be posted on the site's meta or on the main site.

> ask for some recommendations for JS tutorial on stack exchange

I don't know of any site on the network where this would be on-topic at the moment.